# Amazon burstable Instances (e.g. T3) - How much CPU is guaranteed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t3.2xlarge instance in 'unlimited mode'.

Amazon says this instance type has a "Baseline utilization per vCPU" of 40%: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html

I sometimes see that my App is slow and CPU is at 60% while CPU idle is at 0% and CPU steal is at 40%.

In my understanding this should not happen. CPU should go beyond 60% in this example (and it sometimes goes beyond 60%).

Does that mean that T3 CPU is not guaranteed up to 100%? Is it only guaranteed up to "Baseline utilization per vCPU" and all burst on top of that is only available if no other VM on the same hardware needs it?

Comment: I don't know how much is guaranteed, but it is known (and also pretty obvious) that t-instance CPUs are massively oversubscribed, meaning they sell more CPUs than what exists on the hardware - that is the whole point, that's why they have baseline utilization and bursting and why they are cheaper. I would *guess* they probably do have the baseline utilization reserved for you, and anything above that depends on how much CPU time the hardware has free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon support confirmed that if we want to have CPU guaranteed, we need to switch away from a burstable instance. They did not say how much is guaranteed for burstable. So I would say the answer is: "There is no guarantee for any CPU on a burstable instance". They seem to use "baseline utilization" as some kind of soft target, but even that seems not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you don't have any accrued credits to burn when your application needs to burst above the baseline.

> when credits spent are more than credits earned, the
> instance uses the accrued credits to burst above baseline CPU
> utilization. If there are no accrued credits remaining, then the
> instance gradually comes down to baseline CPU utilization and cannot
> burst above baseline until it accrues more credits.

Comment: TY! But I have set it to 'unlimited mode'. This should mean there are always credits to burn, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you have set it to "Unlimited mode" and the average CPU usage exceeds the baseline for 24 hours you will charged for the additional usage at a flat rate per CPU-hour.

You can check your bill if this is not the case you need to create a support ticket to clear things further.

Comment: @gondaljutt and how much CPU time will Peter be able to use in this mode? It's not 100%, apparently.